# Display Button in main layout when CheckBox is checked in Dialog

Tags: android

I have a layout with two buttons. Button 2 is invisible by default.

If the user clicks on button 1, a dialog will open with a CheckBox. I would like button 2 to become visible if the user checks the CheckBox.

This is my code but it's not working:

```
View chechboxveiw = View.inflate(this, R.layout.dingoosetting, null);
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) chechboxveiw.findViewById(R.id.taknafareding);   
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
        new OnCheckedChangeListener() {         
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                if (arg1 == true) {
                // sett my button visible
                    stopacorddinger.setVisibility(4);
                }
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: do you get any warning or error in logcat? if yes please share

Comment: I'd recommend using the constants directly, not their values - `stopacorddinger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`